# Property 'status' does not exist on type 'void'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, axios

I am getting an error when i try to access some property values that i return from nodejs to my react app.

> Property 'status' does not exist on type 'void'
>
> Property 'data' does not exist on type 'void'

A similar error heppens on the catch block inside the signup function in react.

> Property 'response' does not exist on type '{}'

The error does not go away even if i use the retorn Promise type infered by ts on the functions.

I´m using react, typescrip, nodejs and axios on this project.

**nodejs code**

```
async signup(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const { name, email, password } = req.body;

    try {
      let user = await User.findOne({ email: email });
      
      if (user)
        return res.status(400).send({ message: "Email já em uso, por favor informe outro." });

      user = new User({
        fullname: name,
        email: email,
        password: password,
      });

      await user.save()

      return res.status(200).send({ message: "Usuário criado com sucesso!" });
    } catch (error) {
      // return res.status(500).send({ message: "Error de servidor" });
    }
  }
```

**react code**

```
const signup = async (credentials: SignupCredentials) => {
    try {
      const response = await api.post("/user/signup", credentials);
      return response;
    } catch (error) {
      return error?.response;  //error here
    }
  };

const onSubmit = async (data: FormData) => {
    reset();
    setError("");

    const credentials = {
      name: data.fullname,
      email: data.email,
      password: data.password,
    };

    const response = await signup(credentials);

    if (response.status !== 200) {  //error here
      setError(response.data.message); //error here
      return;
    }

    navigate("/login");
  };
```

Comment: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/3612